# Object detection on largest number of classes

Tags: cnn, image-classification, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

Does anyone know any pretrained object detection models to run with python with highest number of objects to be recognised? Yolo finds 80 objects, it is good if I can find a larger number. It would be good to have the highest variety of objects, speed is not that important.